# Where to call method after the condition is fullfill while implementing the duplicate email check using firebase DB in android?

Tags: android, firebase, for-loop, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Actually, I'm fetching the emails from the existing Realtime Databse users record and match them with new email entered if the email match and condition is true it shows an error duplicate email address, and when the condition is false it calls the chooseImage method to select a profile picture.

For checking records I use for loop, the problem I'm facing is when the email is not duplicate then it does not call chooseImage method but the cursor moves outside the loop.

Here is the code for checking duplicate email method:

```
private fun checkingUser(mEmail: String) {
    var isUserAlreadyExist = true
    val mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    mDatabaseRef.child("Users")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    try {
                            for (eachChild in dataSnapshot.children) {
                                val eachUser = eachChild.child("userEmail").value as String?
                                if (eachUser != null) {
                                    if (mEmail.equals(eachUser)) {
                                        isUserAlreadyExist = false

                                        if(!isUserAlreadyExist){
                                            regBtn?.visibility = View.GONE
                                            selectDP?.visibility = View.GONE
                                            progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Email already exist!!\nPlease enter new email address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                                        }
                                        else{
                                            chooseImage() //method doesn't work or don't gets the call
                                        }

                                        break

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                       // chooseImage()  /// method called even when the dublicate email found

                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("checkingUser Issue", e.toString())

                    }


                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
            })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How about having 1 MILLION users?

Are you willing to download the entire "Users" node and check each user on the client, to see if "userEmail" property holds a particular email address? That's a waste of bandwidth and resources.

What you need is a query that looks like this:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val usersRef = rootRef.child("Users")
val queryByUserEmail = usersRef.orderByChild("userMail").equalTo(mEmail)
queryByUserEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (ds in task.result!!.children) {
            if (ds.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "The email already exists!")
            } else {
                chooseImage()
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, task.exception!!.message) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

Java users, should try this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
Query queryByUserEmail = usersRef.orderByChild("userMail").equalTo(mEmail);
queryByUserEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                if (ds.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "The email already exists!");
                } else {
                    chooseImage();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

In this way you'll only download the User objects that satisfy your Query.

Comment: okay this works fine. Can you answer my one other question, if you agree I'll mention there?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked for you, If you have another question, add it here on Stackoverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.